# Error Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)

Tags: flutter, video-player

i was using video_player package and i got this error. I have been searching the answer, but i didn't find one that fit my case.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)
```

this message only showed when i debugged my app on IOS.

and this is my code.

```
class MateriVidioDetailView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ListVideo? video;
  const MateriVidioDetailView({Key? key, this.video}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MateriVidioDetailView> createState() => _MateriVidioDetailViewState();
}

class _MateriVidioDetailViewState extends State<MateriVidioDetailView> {
  late VideoPlayerController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.video!.linkVideo!)
    ..initialize().then((value) => 
    controller.play());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(title: 'Materi Vidio'),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.video!.videoInfo!.name!.toString(),
              style: regheadingStyle,
            ),
            Text(widget.video!.videoInfo!.description!.toString()),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  child: VideoPlayer(controller)
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the `widget.video!.linkVideo!` has the correct link?

Comment: One more thing initialize your video controller after `super.initState();`

Comment: @TariqulIslam yes it has the correct link

Comment: @TariqulIslam i tried to init the video controller like you said but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

better_player library worked for me without any issues for both devices, I had to switch, couldn't find solution that worked for me.